# How to detect null values in a vector

Tags: r, vector, null

Whats the best way to detect null values in a vector?

If I have the vector below and want to know that the 4th position is null how would I do that?

```
vx <- c(1, 2, 3, NULL, 5)
```

`is.null()` returns only `FALSE`:

```
is.null(vx)
# [1] FALSE
```

and I'd like to get:

```
 FALSE FALSE FALSE TRUE FALSE
```

Comment: A vector can't contain `NULL`. Look at `length(vx)`.

Comment: put `NA`  instead of `NULL` in case you are creating your own vector and then try `is.na(vx)`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, `NULL` will not appear in `length(vx)`. It is a special object in R for undefined values. From CRAN documentation:

> NULL represents the null object in R: it is a reserved word. NULL is
>   often returned by expressions and functions whose value is undefined.

But your question can still have learning opportunities with respect to lists. It will show up there. As in:

```
vlist <- list(1, 2, 3, NULL, 5)
```

Trying to identify the `NULL` value in a very large dataset can be tricky for novice R users. There are different techniques, but here is one that worked for me when I needed it.

```
!unlist(lapply(vlist, is.numeric))
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE

#or as user Kara Woo added. Much better than my convoluted code
sapply(vlist, is.null)
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE

#suggestion by @Roland
vapply(vlist, is.null, TRUE)
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

If there are characters, then substitute in `is.character` or whatever class applies.

Comment: Is there a reason to do `!unlist(lapply(vlist, is.numeric))` instead of `sapply(vlist, is.null)`? The former could get complicated if you have list items that are a mix of character, numeric, etc.

Comment: It's even more efficient (and safer) to use `vapply`.

Comment: Will add to the answer @Roland.

Answer (score 7):

Its possible that someone (like me) may come looking for `is.null()`, really needing `is.na()`. If so, remind yourself (as I did) that R has both a `NULL` and `NA` object. `NULL` signifies that there is no value whereas `NA` signifies that the value is unknown. If you are looking for missing values in a vector of values, what you're probably after is `is.na()`.