# NULL different length result with list and vector

Tags: r

Why does NULL behave differently with `length()` when used with `c()` and `list()`?
When I try `length(c(1,2,3,NULL))` it gives the output 3 but with `length(list(1,2,3,NULL))` it gives the output 4.

Comment: A `list` can contain `NULL`, a vector can not.

Comment: Related reading: [How to detect null values in a vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30716377/how-to-detect-null-values-in-a-vector)

Comment: Try just doing  `foo <- c(1,2,3,NULL)`  and `bar <- list(1,2,3,NULL)`  and see what you get.